# CSS está afetando o console do Stack Snippet

Tags: bug, status-intencional, stack-snippets

Fui responder uma pergunta recentemente e utilizei um exemplo bem simples, apenas aplicando uma regra CSS ao primeiro `<div>` do snippet. Porém, notei que essa regra é aplicada também à que exibe as mensagens do `console.log()`:

Rode o snippet abaixo, notará que o que deveria exibir algo como:

> [image: console no stack snippet]

Note como ficou ao clicar em "Executar":

```js
setInterval(() => {
    console.log('Mensagem do console.');
}, 1000);
```

```css
div { height: 60px; width: 160px; background: red }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Esse elemento não deveria ter uma regra específica para impedir esse tipo de comportamento?

---

## English Version

**Title:** CSS affecting Stack Snippet's console

I was answering a question recently, and used a pretty simple example, applying only a CSS rule to the snippet's first `<div>`. However, I noticed that that same rule is also applied to the `<div>` that shows `console.log()`'s messages:

Execute the snippet below, and note that it should show something like:

> [image: console in stack snippet]

Notice how it went when you hit "Execute:"

```js
setInterval(() => {
    console.log('Mensagem do console.');
}, 1000);
```

```css
div { height: 60px; width: 160px; background: red }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Shouldn't this element have a specific rule to prevent this type of begavior?

Comment: Não tira não, vou customizar o console de todas minhas perguntas e respostas sobre JavaScript :D

Comment: Renan eu editei porque acho que o exemplo inicial esta um pouco dificil de compreender, o `setInterval` creio que fica mais evidente e o print serve de comparativo, mas se achar necessidade reverta.

Comment: cross-post do problema https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279561/198279 (apesar de no comentário estar afirmado que corrigiram, a sua postagem mostra que não), vamos aguardar (cc @JNat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obrigado por reportares isto. Isto está a acontecer porque a consola do Stack Snippets não é uma consola "real" (como a do browser). É um *hack* útil que usa um div para se conter a si próprio.

Neste caso, a tua regra CSS para cada `div` acaba por visar também a consola. Podes resolver isto de duas maneiras:

1. Tornar a regra CSS mais específica (talvez como um nome de classe).
2. Desactivar a consola para este snippet se não precisares dela (há uma *checkbox* no editor!).

Diz-me se isto ajudar!

---

Thank-you for reporting this. This is happening because the Stack Snippets Console is not a "real" console (like in the browser). It is a helpful hack that uses a div to contain itself.

In this case, your CSS rule for every `div` results in targeting the console also. You can solve it in 2 different ways:

1. Make the CSS rule more specific (perhaps with a class name).
2. Disable the console for this snippet if you don't need it (there's a checkbox in the editor!)

Let me know if that helps!